# How can I make a 3d Touch Quick Action open a certain view controller in my app?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an app that has a 3D Touch quick action that I want to have it launch a certain view controller in my app.

Could someone help inform me what the correct code would be to launch a certain view controller in my app?

In my AppDelegate.swift I have this... but it's not working.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        if shortcutItem.type == "Matt-Held.blackshirtMarket.viewproducts" {

            func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
                segue.destination as!
                productViewController
            }
```

The view controller I want to "launch" when the 3d quick action is pressed is called "productViewController"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check my answer please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to instantiate your target VC from the storyboard, like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let targetVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"productViewController") as! ProductViewController
```

Then you want to decide what to do with it.  Some common options might be a) present it modally, b) push it onto an existing Nav Controller, or c) just make it the rootVC of your app's window. Here's how you would do the latter:

```
 // option B) push onto an existing nav controller
 if let navC = window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController? {
     navC.pushViewController(targetVC, animated: false)
 } 

 // option C) just make it the root VC
 window?.rootViewController = targetVC
```

I think the other methods are well documented elsewhere. What you want depends on the navigation structure of your app (which you didn't include in the question).

Apart from that, do take a look at the sample shortcuts application. And remember that this method, performActionForShortcut, is called when a quick action is used to activate your app from the background. So you will also need to deal with launching your app via a shortcut.

Comment: Ok. So I added this to my code. It builds fine, however, it shows a "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error when I try to launch it using the 3d quick action.

Comment: Here are a few screenshots: https://d.pr/i/2hmVwj (navigation layout), https://d.pr/i/6HNREK (appDelegate.swift file)... Maybe those will help! Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you know how to use the debugger to isolate where exactly your app is crashing? Also, I strongly encourage you to take a second look at the shortcuts sample application.

Comment: Is this the debugger data?

Comment: 2018-01-18 20:14:34.358680-0600 blackshirtMarket[1768:677674] [Accessibility] ****************** Loading GAX Client Bundle ****************
2018-01-18 20:14:41.620670-0600 blackshirtMarket[1768:677674] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x1c82607c0>) doesn't contain a view

Comment: controller with identifier 'productViewController''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x184e6e364 0x1840b4528 0x18ed3bfe4 0x104834634 0x104834924 0x18e69ce90 0x18e6992c8 0x18e925b24 0x18f0aa7d0 0x18f0aa674 0x18ee182dc 0x18efb13dc 0x18ee1818c 0x18ebfc78c 0x18ea9e2d4 0x187532ca4 0x10565928c 0x1056659e4 0x1875667f8 0x18756649c 0x187566a38 0x184e1697c 0x184e168fc 0x184e16184 0x184e13d5c 0x184d33e58 0x186be0f84 0x18e48867c 0x104834c34 0x18485056c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: What this means is that you have not set the "Storyboard ID" for this view controller (or you have set it to something other than "productViewController").  You will find this under the identity inspector for your VC in the interface builder.

Comment: Awesome! That works now... Is there a way to get the "back button" to bring it back to the main view controller? If the user would want to? Thanks so much!

Comment: Sure, that's what I was alluding to with option b), "push it onto an existing nav controller".  That seems to be the case with your app.  Let me edit the answer to show that in more detail.

Comment: That's perfect. Works great now. Thanks for everything!